# ng-model in ng-repeat - how to send values to server

Tags: angularjs

im using ng-repeat to create dynamic number of textboxs.

```js
<div class="orgevent" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(numOfEvents)  track by $index">
  <input class="dest" type="text" value="Free text" ng-model="i.freeText">
</div>
```

i want (on click) to take the values that the user write in the textBox and send it to the server,
how can i do it?

i tried to take it in the JS by ng-model but the value is always "undefined"

Comment: Please show the controller too. What's `i`? What `getNumber(numOfEvents)` return? Where is the `ngClick` part you're talking about? There is not enough details in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-model as array and read it on click. Take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/ucskyv67/74/

```
app.controller("cookieCtrl", function ($scope, $cookies) {
    $scope.numbers= [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  $scope.userVals=[];
  $scope.getVal= function(){
    console.log($scope.userVals);
  }
});


<div ng-app="cookieApp" ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
    <div class="orgevent" ng-repeat="i in numbers  track by $index">
      <input class="dest" type="text" value="Free text" ng-model="userVals[$index]">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="getVal()">Read</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to add ng-change to your input and implement a method in your controller to call the server-

```
<input ng-change="handleChange(i.freeText)" class="dest" type="text" value="Free text" ng-model="i.freeText">
```